# Equivalent of Java's 'public static final string'

Tags: kotlin

In my Java project I have a class where I declare many project constants using *public static final String* attributes:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String KIND_NAME = "user";
    public static final String AVATAR_IMAGE_ID = "avatarImageId";
    public static final String AVATAR_IMAGE_URL = "avatarImageUrl";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    public static final String TOTAL_SCORE_COLUMN = "totalScore";
    ...
}
```

So I can use this in many different places in my project:

```
...
String userName = user.getProperty(Constants.KIND_NAME);
...
```

So far I have found some different ways to implement this in Kotlin, like: *companion objects* or *data class*. What is the best equivalent code in Kotlin?

Comment: I want to emulate: _public static final_

Comment: use *object* to declare your constants class. and define all as *const val*

Answer (score 10):

@Todd's answer will produce an `INSTANCE` instance of class `Constants`, which is sometimes unexpected. A better alternative is:

```
// file-level
@file:JvmName("Constants")
const val KIND_NAME = "user"
const val AVATAR_IMAGE_ID = "avatarImageId"
const val AVATAR_IMAGE_URL = "avatarImageUrl"
const val NAME_COLUMN = "name"
const val TOTAL_SCORE_COLUMN = "totalScore"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a simple `class` with a `compaion object` and some `const val`s:

```
class Constants {
    companion object {
        const val KIND_NAME = "user"
        const val AVATAR_IMAGE_ID = "avatarImageId"
        const val AVATAR_IMAGE_URL = "avatarImageUrl"
        const val NAME_COLUMN = "name"
        const val TOTAL_SCORE_COLUMN = "totalScore"
    }
}
```

Comment: those `val`s should be `const` unless you want this to look like`Constants.Companion.getKIND_NAME()` on the Java side.

Comment: Yes. I read up on objects, and if you are using java, then it would look like that.

Comment: Downvoters should explain their reasoning, this approach is perfectly valid, depending on how `Constants` is used otherwise.

Comment: @ice1000 because `Constants` should have a `private constructor` and the vals should be `const`.